# WooCommerce single product page customisation: template files or hooks?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I have to customize some layout and data output for single product pages, and for the loop as well.

This leads to a way too long PHP file where I coded all the stuff needed with the help of the `remove_action`, `add_action` and `add_filter` functions. I manage to get what I want intended to, but I'm concerned about performances and further updates / modifications of the code.

I imagined I could achieve the same, maybe even a bit more more easily using a `/woocommerce` directory in my child theme, and editing the necessary files in `/single-product` for example.

However, my concern is performance and maintainability. Is it a better solution to go single files edits, or to come up with 2K+ lines of code in a hassle of remove/add actions (in server load / page generation / future modifications to be made) ?

On the other hand, I came across this warning in WooCommerce files :

```
HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
(the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
maintain compatibility. 
...
```

Is this really something to be concerned of ? Does it happen regularly ?

Comment: Hooks always first, then if there is no other way, template override.

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce plugin **updates are frequent**, but the **major updates** comes after **around 2-3 months**.

So, if you're worried about your code not being compatible with newer versions of WooCommerce, then using hooks and filters as you've already implemented is a better approach.

Also, updating a WooVommerce plugin is always a good approach, since they release security patches and performance upgrades every once a while.

So I'd say, stick to your current approach in order to **maintain compatibility with newer versions.**

Comment: Thanks for this insight. I will stick to the action/filters method for now.